# JSON: Unknown Tags in a JSON file

Tags: javascript, json, flutter, dart, tags

Currently accessing a [community public](https://raw.communitydragon.org/latest/cdragon/tft/en_gb.json) .json file, having worked only with HTML, Python, Dart & Flutter, I have little to no knowledge in other programming languages and I found some ambiguous tags and reference patterns (samples below).

```
 {
            "desc": "The holder gains @BonusAP@ additional Spell Power.",
            "effects": {
                "AP": 30.0,
                "{d49caf5d}": 50.0
            },
            "from": [
                3,
                3
            ],
            "icon": "ASSETS/Maps/Particles/TFT/TFT_Item_RabadonsDeathcap.dds",
            "id": 33,
            "name": "Rabadon's Deathcap"
        },
```

```
 {
            "desc": "Grants @CritChance@% Critical Strike Chance (including components). Each point of Critical Strike Chance above 100% becomes +@BonusCritDmgPerCritAbove100@% Critical Strike Damage.<br><br><tftitemrules>[Unique - Only One Per Champion]</tftitemrules>",
            "effects": {
                "AD": 15.0,
                "CritChance": 75.0,
                "{45c7ed6b}": 1.0
            },
            "from": [
                1,
                9
            ],
            "icon": "ASSETS/Maps/Particles/TFT/TFT_Item_InfinityEdge.dds",
            "id": 19,
            "name": "Infinity Edge"
        }
```

TLDR;:

```
@SomeString@
<tftitemrules>some string</tftitemrules>,
// under "effects": 
{ 
    ... 
    "{45c7ed6b}": 1.0,
}
```

1. I would like to know, which language is exploiting this kind of tags/custom tags.
2. Is there any chance that `"{45c7ed6b}"` refers to something in the description? If so, please explain, I am clueless.
3. Is there any library in `Dart` that can make my work easier to exploit these tags?

Comment: From the JSON perspective, these are just string keys like any other.  I suspect that these properties are serialized from some other format, and some sort of constant class property names or something were not able to be converted directly.  +1 though, I'm curious what serialized this as well.  Perhaps you could give more details as to what this file is?

Comment: @Brad https://raw.communitydragon.org/latest/cdragon/tft/
This is a json file containing information about items used in a game called Teamfight Tactics which is related to the well known League of Legends.
We are currently working on an app offering information to players about various aspects of the game. Please let me know if you need any further info & kindly take a look at the url I just shared in the comment.

Comment: Oh, this kind of game is way above my head.  I think the most complicated game I can play is Asteroids.  :-)  All I can suggest is contacting the folks who made it and asking them what those properties indicate.  There is probably a file of constants they can provide.

Answer (score 0):

1 - It could be written in any kind of language. But considering it's
`"icon": "ASSETS/Maps/Particles/TFT/TFT_Item_InfinityEdge.dds",`
part, it's directdraw surface file which is an openGL format and it can also be used by many languages but has many examples with C++ and C#.

- [DDS image format loader](http://www.mindcontrol.org/%7Ehplus/graphics/dds-info/)
- [Programming Guide for DDS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/direct3ddds/dx-graphics-dds-pguide?redirectedfrom=MSDN)

2 - It seems effects are property values of game code as described not directly in desc. And the "{45c7ed6b}" tag is refer to

> Now converts every 1% excess critical strike chance into 1% bonus
> critical strike damage

which is only known by knowing developer's intentions. Either they put names as temporary or new company policy for variable naming.

[Infinity Edge - TFT item](https://leagueoflegends.fandom.com/wiki/Infinity_Edge_(Teamfight_Tactics))

3 - By exploiting, what do you intend to do? Visualize them in the Flutter app or??

Comment: Thank you for the detailed answer @KemalTarhan . By expoloiting, I mean using this json content in a "Items" page, which is like a wiki that offers info about each item. However, as you can see, I cannot just use the `"desc":` values as is, given that there are some special tags and references, so I am looking to create a class that takes these references and finds them in the `"effects":` key-value pair, and in order to do that I need to understand each reference. At this point I am failing to understand keys like `{45c7ed6b}`. How did you figure it out?

Comment: I searched all files inside community dragon's raw folders but found no clue. With considering effects property as item's effects I compared like for example item Hush(6) has this properties,
`                "MagicResist": 25.0,
                "Mana": 20.0,
                "SilenceDuration": 4.0,
                "{2275757b}": 20.0,
                "{4516a18d}": 4.0
`
and from [Hush - TFT](https://leagueoflegends.fandom.com/wiki/Hush_(Teamfight_Tactics)) `Passive : Basic attacks have a 20% chance to Silence main target for 4 seconds.` which suits to those tags. Better ask to cdragon.